# Adjust project hours based on priority

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, scheduled-tasks, hour

i want to spread the Estimated hours in C column across the 5 days in each row, based on what priority was chosen in B column. So,

1. 'High' priority will get max weightage of 1, i.e. more hours to complete project.
2. 'Medium' priority will get medium weightage of 0.67 i.e. medium hours to complete project.
3. 'Low' priority will get the lowest weightage of 0.34 i.e least hours to complete project.
4. Now, the total number of hours (Row 8) for each day should not exceed 8
   hours per day. so each column cell value has to be adjusted automatically.

can someone help me with the formula to be inputted in E3:I7 ?

[image: adjust hours based on priority]

Here is a link to the file which contains all the formulae:

[PSchedule Template.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Am1wNPJDit1whx5eRTy_c1qb_tmE)

Comment: Please show, in your original post, what your expected outcome would be?

Comment: This doesn't appear to anything more complex than pre-algebra maths. What is the formula you are currently using?

Comment: Makes no sense to spend *any* time on "low" items when you already have 44 hours allocated to "high" (and you only have 40 hours total to allocate)?

Comment: i have shared the link to this file from my onedrive account in my original mail. cannot paste the formulae here as it will not render correctly.

Comment: @TimWilliams, i provided just a snapshot of 40 hours per week (5 days), but the Est. Hours for each project may be spread across more weeks, depending upon how long each project runs. i am trying to make sense of how to spread the hours vertically i.e. not more than 8 hours per day. So need some formula that would automatically adjust the column hours (daily hours), so that their total summation only adds upto not more than 8 hours.

Comment: It is not appropriate to change the question after receiving an answer it open my answer up for down votes as it does not now answer the question above. The new question should have been a new post.

Comment: @ScottCraner, sorry about that. didnt realize. should i post a new question with the same subject and file? let me know.

Comment: I've reverted your post back to it's original question - people have spent hours working on this for you to just change the question afterwards. If your question has changed that much, then it needs to be a new post - otherwise people get downvoted for an answer that no longer fits when in fact it's the question that no longer fits...

Answer (score 0):

This is about as close as I can get without circular references:

```
=IF(SUM($D3:D3)+(E$1/(SUMPRODUCT(($C$3:$C$7*SUMIF($I$12:$I$14,$B$3:$B$7,$K$12:$K$14)))-SUM($D$3:D$7)))*(($C3*VLOOKUP($B3,$I$12:$K$14,3,FALSE))-SUM($D3:D3))>$C3,$C3-SUM($D3:D3),(E$1/(SUMPRODUCT(($C$3:$C$7*SUMIF($I$12:$I$14,$B$3:$B$7,$K$12:$K$14)))-SUM($D$3:D$7)))*(($C3*VLOOKUP($B3,$I$12:$K$14,3,FALSE))-SUM($D3:D3)))
```

It is not perfect but close.

Put it in E3 copy over and down

[image]

Comment: Awesome! this works fine and it give me 8 hours per day, if the projects are aligned the same day. However, the Estimated End Date may go ahead as shown in the Actual End date. However, i am having trouble in determining the correct working dates in range I5:JI5 when i select Day, Week, or month in the dropdown in C5. The actual dates should show the same dates even if i choose, Day, Week or Month. But they donot! Let me know what am i doing wrong. i am sure it has to do with the 22 Working days calculation for month selection. I have attached the latest working copy in my original post.

Comment: It is not appropriate to change the question after receiving an answer it open my answer up for down votes as it does not now answer the question above.  The new question should have been a new post.